# Finding sum of subarrays using Java

Tags: java, arrays

My problem is in the function  Sum(int z) which should return the sum of all items in sub-array at index z or returns 0 if invalid index.
My current code is

```
public int[][] data;
public calculate(int[][] source) {
        data = source;
    }
    public int size() {
    
    return data.length;
}

 public boolean isValidSubsetIndex(int z) {
        
          if (z<0 || z>= size())
          return false;
                
        return true;
    }
public int sum(int z) {
        int x=0;
        if (isValidSubsetIndex(z)  == true) {
        for (int i = 0; i < data[z].length;i++) {
            for(int j= i; j<i+1; j++)
                    x = x + data[i][j];
                    
            }
        return x;
        }
        return 0;
        
    }
aP = new Analytics(new int[][]{{30, 10, 40},
        {50, 20, 80},
        {10, 60, 30},
        {60, 60, 60}});
       

    aHD = new Analytics(new int[][]{{-30, 10, -40},
        {},
        {-10, 60},
        {-60},
        {-20, -20, -20, -20, -20},
        {-20, -20},
        {-20},
        {},
        {50},
        {10, 30, 20}});
```

The test that it is failing is given below. My current code only provides the first result correct (sum 80 for sum(0)).
if sum(1) result should be 150,
if sum (2) result should be 100

```
public void testSumHD() {
        testSumD();
        int[] sumHD = {-60, 0, 50, -60, -100, -40, -20, 0, 50, 60};
        
        for(int i=0; i < sumHD.length; i++) {
            assertEquals(sumHD[i], aHD.sum(i));
        }
        assertEquals(0, aHD.sum(-1));
        assertEquals(0, aHD.sum(10)); 
    }
```

Comment: Could you include a bit more code as we do not know what, for example, aP and aHD are

Comment: assertEquals(80, aP.sum(0)); means that when sum(0) is called the result should be 80. The problem is in the logic of my Sum(int z) function. Ignore the aP, aHD part

Comment: Inside of sum you say this: `if (z<0 || z>= size())`. What is the value of size()?

Comment: it is the data.length. I have edited the question.

Comment: BTW you dont have to do this: `if (isValidSubsetIndex(z)  == true) {` you can just use: `if (isValidSubsetIndex(z)) {`

Comment: What do you understand "sum of all items in subarray at index _z_" to mean? _I_ think it means `data[z][0]+data[z][1]+...+data[z][data[z].length-1]`, but that's not what you're adding up.

Comment: CORRECT!! I just replaced [i] with [z] and it's working.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was   x = x + data[z][j];